# Remove dependency completely from Npm

Tags: angular, npm, frontend, node-modules, package.json

I wanna remove some dependencies completely from my project i.e package.json, package-lock.json
Package.json

```
{
  "name": "application",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^13.3.7",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^13.3.7",
    "@angular/animations": "^13.3.11",
    "@angular/cdk": "^12.2.13",
    "@angular/common": "^13.3.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "^13.3.11",
    "@angular/core": "^13.3.11",
    "@angular/forms": "^13.3.11",
    "@angular/material": "^12.2.13",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^12.2.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^13.3.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^13.3.11",
    "@angular/router": "^13.3.11",
```

for example I wanna remove @angular/forms
so I will give this command

```
npm uninstall @angular/forms
```

But seems its only remove from Node modules
How could I remove this completely.

Comment: This question needs more details to get a useful answer. When you say "it only removes from Node modules" what do you mean? What are you seeing and what do you want to see?

Comment: Delete it from the package.json and package-lock.json files?

Comment: `npm uninstall xxx --save`?

Answer (score 0):

Package.json is under your control and you need to edit it to fit your dependencies.

So if you would like to remove dependencies this is where you start.

remove them from package.json and run `npm prune`.
you could also just remove node_modules and rerun `npm install`

Comment: So does npm prune remove dependency from package-lock.json also
For exam if i have removed it from package.json and run npm prune so does this automatically remove dependency from package-lock.json also

Comment: Good question, I am not sure but I think npm uninstall would remove it from the package-lock.json, sorry for the late reply.